# Dynamically add colors in $theme-colors in Scss Functions Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, sass

I'm trying to add dynamic color through javascript using variables and then trying to use scss functions for that color, but I am getting below errors

```js
Module build failed(from. / node_modules / sass - loader / dist / cjs.js):
  SassError: $color2: var (--
    default -primary - color) is not a color.╷
106│ @return mix($color - base, $color, $level * $theme - color - interval);│ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ╵
node_modules\ bootstrap\ scss\ _functions.scss 106: 11 theme - color - level()
node_modules\ bootstrap\ scss\ _tables.scss 101: 38 @import
node_modules\ bootstrap\ scss\ bootstrap.scss 17: 9 @import
src\ styles.scss 38: 9 @import
src\ app\ locations\ containers\ locations\ locations.component.scss 1: 9 root stylesheet
```

Below is the approach I am using to add the color dynamically

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-primary-color', "#dd9e9e");
```

```css
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins';

$primary-color: var(--default-primary-color);

$theme-colors: ( // "primary": #e4b5b1,
// "primary": #00b4b4,
'primary': var(--default-primary-color), 
);

.btn-secondary {
  background: theme-color("primary");
  border-color: theme-color("primary");
}
```

In the above code, I need to add the dynamic value to theme-colors

**also if I add directly the $primary-color by not using the themes-color then it's working but I want to use theme-color**

```css
.primary-background {
  background-color: $primary-color; // works
}

the above approach will work .primary-background {
  background-color: theme-color("primary"); //-> doesn't work
}
```

I tried to find many approaches but didn't find any solution for them

Please help me as I m stuck here and not able to continue.

if this approach doesn't work please suggest any other approach using ngrx or any other method.

Comment: Can you confirm how the colours are dynamically selected? Does this happen in the front-end (i.e. as a result of user interaction through JavaScript)? Are there a set number of colours that the dynamic value could be picked from?

Comment: no, a particular color will be given by the backend which needs to be set on the front end using js function for ex. from the backend they give the string as 'red' then in js document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-primary-color', "red"); 
in the above function, I have passed as red and that will apply on $theme-colors - 'primary' which can be accessed all over the application

Comment: In which case I would suggest creating a SASS map of all possible colours, and then add a class for each colour in the map. When the colour is set on the front end, change the class at the top level, which would then update the colours throughout the page. Because the SASS gets compiled BEFORE it reaches the client, and therefore before the user selects a colour, there is no way of injecting a selected colour into the SASS.

Comment: okay thank you @Bladeski ill try to use sass map and let see if it works

Comment: @Bladeski i cant use map as my team suggesting for theme-colors

Answer (score 2):

> I think you must define color in :root

```js
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--default-primary-color', "green");
```

```css
  
 :root {
    --default-primary-color: red;
}
h1{color:var(--default-primary-color)}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

@vinuta, You could rewrite it to match what is below and confirm if it works.

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins';
    
// colors
:root {
  --primary: #2F80ED;
  --secondary: #FF0000;
}

$theme-colors: () !default;
$theme-colors: map-merge(
  (
    "primary": var(--primary),
    "secondary": var(--secondary),
  ),
  $theme-colors
 );

// Additionally; The function that handles the theme colors 
@function theme-color($key: "primary") {
  @return map-get($theme-colors, $key);
} 
// You would usually have this, among other functions in a separate functions.scss file and imported after the variables import)
```

[Theming Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/)

Comment: i tried it dint work giving primary-color is undefined may be angular doesn't support it

Comment: @vinuta I have updated the code (Now using CSS variables for the colors).

Comment: Try with this now.

Comment: sure ill try and let you know

Comment: @vinuta progress?

Answer (score 0):

you can use map-get like

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables';
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins';

$primary-color: var(--default-primary-color);

$theme-colors: ( 
  "primary": $primary-color,
);

.primary-background {
  background-color: map-get($theme-colors,"primary");
}
```

Comment: $theme-colors: ( 
  "primary": #e4b5b1, //// i want to update this color 
);
$theme-colors: ( 
  "primary": $--default-primary-color || var (----default-primary-color),
);

Comment: ok that the same but var(--default-primary-color) doesn't exist in bootstrap.. so Does this mean that you have already defined it in your project?

Comment: yes I have already defined in ts file because the color I am getting is from the backend that's why I need to add it dynamically not static color

Comment: I am getting value from the backend like red, blue (in hex value of course) which keeps on changing hence I need to add the color in theme color only becz i need to change at many level

Comment: so if it is in :root{} of bootstrap you need to import the _root.scss file to

Comment: like the below example?
:root {
color: $color 
}

Comment: If you open your inspector on your page you can see your variable in :root{}?

Comment: I made this exemple for you is react app but the logic is the same : [codeSandbox](https://ifzcv.csb.app/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234026/discussion-between-daphaz-and-vinuta).